# Wxwidgets setup.h file changes when cloned from git

Tags: c++, g++, wxwidgets

I am using wxWidgets library to compile an application. The application source code along with wxWidgets libraries are taken from a git remote repository and it seems `setup.h` file is changed along the way from another local repository to my local repository.

Now the compilation of an application produces the following error, does anyone has experience of dealing with this.

```
#error "wxUSE_LIBMSPACK must be defined"
```

The reason for error is described here but I could not find the `setip0.h` file.

https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/include/wx/chkconf.h

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify, but based on the error I assume you're trying to build on windows.

Just delete the file /include/msw/setup.h

The try to build the wxWidgets libraries again.  All of the included build files will then copy /include/msw/setup0.h as their first step and then proceed as normal.